# I cannot change the excel number format when is generated by SSIS

Tags: c#, excel, ssis

I am generating an excel file with SSIS, when the file is generated I open it and try to set the columns to a specific number format but it does not work, nothing happens.

But if after I set the format I change the value manually, the new value is formatted properly.

Every file and sheet are generated dynamically, I do not want use excel templates. The plan is modify the formats with open xml after generation but I cannot modify the formats even manually.

Any idea?

Comment: the connection string i am using is for xslx (2007):Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Path\file.xlsx;
Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 xml;HDR=YES";

Comment: Please add code to demonstrate what you have attempted

Comment: In fact I do not use any code. I am using SSIS controls to achieve it. the process creates a table using the excel destination connection. a data flow control fill the data from the database and that's it

Comment: SSIS is likely setting the values as text, which are then immune to number formatting. Since the data type of columns is derived from the workbook, you'll need to look at how you're generating the sheet and/or fix your data types with the advanced editor.

Comment: I already did it. the metadata before write into the excel connection are right and the advance editor have the properties set with the correct data types. I have created a test package without dynamic createtion and is the same. I create a spreadsheet with 3 columns (int, date, money) but with the general type. I query the database and export to excel with the correct metadata and datatype but the excel resulted is not well formated